# SQL Server query result for all shipping products

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a product table as below.

[image]

Where I want to get each product detail where its product_ship_flag is "YES" for all the products of same the order_number. If any of the product_ship_flag is "No" then the whole order_number should not be in the output. If all product_ship_flag as "No" then should not be in the output.

**The Output will look like:** 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

***Edited***: Few members are not even trying to understand the problem, And some are not able to answer the problem so devoting the question. Please show some sportiness.

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text...

Comment: please click on the image. might you can get its large result

Comment: images are not allowed in my work location ..post sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
If the inner query does not return anything for that order that means all the product has flag_ship equal to Yes

```
select * from product p
where not exists (
    select '1' from product p2
    where p2.order_number = p1.order_number
    and p2.product_ship_flag = 'No')
```

Comment: @Navid_H, by taking reference of your query i made it like "select * from products_order p1
where p1.order_number not in (
    select p2.order_number from products_order p2
    where p2.product_ship_flag = 'No') "

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a basic query like this works?

```
Select * from product where product_ship_flag = 'Yes' group by order_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
    select * from product where orderno not in  (select orderno, count(case when product_ship_flaf='No' then 1 end) from product
    group by orderno
    having count(case when product_ship_flaf='No' then 1 end)>=1)A
```

Answer (score 0):

@irfan_m, the logic can be captured with the MIN operator. When you do a subquery and using a column called flag for example. You can easily pull out the orders based on your requirement.
See a mock up below:

```
DECLARE @Producttbl TABLE (id int, order_number varchar(20), product_id varchar(20), stock_cnt int, product_ship_flag VARCHAR(3))
INSERT INTO @Producttbl
SELECT 1,'001','SKU1', 1, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 2,'001','SKU2', 2, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 3,'001','SKU3', 1, 'No' union all
SELECT 4,'002','SKU1', 1, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 5,'002','SKU2', 2, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 6,'003','SKU1', 1, 'No' union all
SELECT 7,'003','SKU2', 2, 'No' 

SELECT *
FROM
 @Producttbl P
 JOIN (
        SELECT order_number, Flag=MIN(product_ship_flag)
        --product_ship_flag is 
        ---"YES" : for all the products of same the order_number
        --If any of the product_ship_flag is "No" then the whole order_number should not be in the output.
        --If all product_ship_flag as "No" then should not be in the output.
        FROM
            @Producttbl

        GROUP BY 
        order_number
    )S ON
    S.order_number=P.order_number
WHERE
    S.Flag='Yes'
```

see result below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A left join could be handy in this case.

```
DECLARE @ProducttblTEST TABLE (id int, order_number varchar(20), product_id 
varchar(20), stock_cnt int, product_ship_flag VARCHAR(3))
INSERT INTO @ProducttblTEST
SELECT 1,'001','SKU1', 1, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 2,'001','SKU2', 2, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 3,'001','SKU3', 1, 'No' union all
SELECT 4,'002','SKU1', 1, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 5,'002','SKU2', 2, 'Yes' union all
SELECT 6,'003','SKU1', 1, 'No' union all
SELECT 7,'003','SKU2', 2, 'No' 

select * from @ProducttblTEST a
left join (select * from @ProducttblTEST where product_ship_flag = 'no') b on 
a.order_number = b.order_number
where a.product_ship_flag = 'yes' and b.order_number is null
```